# Не получается установить scrot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

Иду по докуменации и устанавлюваю пакет pyautogui через команду `pipenv install pyautogui`. Все отлично, дальше нужно установить scrot, использую команду `pipenv install scrot` иии,  поялвяется такая ошибка:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement scrot (from -r /tmp/pipenv-vssh_mzd-requirements/pipenv-y_bgu20j-requirement.txt (line 1)) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for scrot (from -r /tmp/pipenv-vssh_mzd-requirements/pipenv-y_bgu20j-requirement.txt (line 1))
```

Comment: `"Не получается установить pyautogui"` -> `"Все отлично"` `"дальше нужно установить scrot, использую команду pipenv install scrot иии, поялвяется такая ошибка:"`? O_o

Comment: Прочитайте заголовк вопроса и не вырывайте фразы из контекста.

Comment: Скорее всего нет такого модуля `scrot`. А зачем вам эта утилита линукса? `pyautogui` умеет делать скриншоты через opencv или pillow

Comment: А где я вырывал? Вы написали в теме, что не смогли `pyautogui` установить, но он у вас установился. А проблема возникла с установкой `scrot`

Comment: Если нет такого модуля, то я не понимаю для чего его просят тут (https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) установить.
В теме написано про scrot, а не pyautogui

Comment: "On Linux, **additionally** you need to install the scrot application": `sudo apt-get install scrot`. Там команда установки приложения для линукса, а не модуля для питона. И как я писал выше, скорее всего, вам оно не понадобится, т.к. скриншоты pyautogui может сделать и с pillow (по-моему, оно вместо с pyautogui ставится), и через opencv. Т.е. этот вопрос все-таки именно к scrot, а не к pyautogui, т.к. оно ставится дополнительно к нему

Comment: Охх, сколько времени я убил устанавлия scrot и остальные приложения как модуль... Просто при запуске файла возвращается такая ошибка 
`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python3-tk (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python3-tk
`
и я подумал, что это из-за отсуствия таких модулей.